# react ref.example.value vs. e.target.value

Tags: javascript, events, reactjs, target, ref

I have the below component that works fine with `this.refs.searchString.value` but would it work if I just `event.target.value` instead? If so, which one is preferred method? What's the pros and cons of each?

```
const SearchBar = React.createClass({

  handleSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const formattedSearchString = this.refs.searchString.value.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, "").toLowerCase()
    this.refs.searchString.value = ''
    this.props.submitSearch(formattedSearchString)
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <form className="form form-group has-info col-md-4 text-align-center" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input className="search-input form-control" type="text" ref="searchString"  placeholder=" . . . enter pokemon name" />
        <button className="btn btn-info btn-raised" type="submit" name="button">Search!</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: `event.target.value` is preferred. Don't Overuse Refs. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the documentation, [we shouldn't overuse refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs), the preferred method is to use `event.target.value` using [Controlled Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

```
const SearchBar = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
     return {textValue: ""};
  },
  onTextChange(evt) {
     this.setState({textValue: evt.target.value});
  },
  handleSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const formattedSearchString = this.state.textValue.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, "").toLowerCase()
    this.refs.searchString.value = ''
    this.props.submitSearch(formattedSearchString)
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <form className="form form-group has-info col-md-4 text-align-center" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input className="search-input form-control" type="text" value={this.state.textValue} onChange={this.onTextChange}  placeholder=" . . . enter pokemon name" />
        <button className="btn btn-info btn-raised" type="submit" name="button">Search!</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: What if you already had the ref created for other purposes? Would it still make sense to introduce event.target and use both?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `event.target.value`, you have to keep track of state of form inputs with `useState`. Everytime state changes, that means after each keystroke,  it will rerender the app which is very expensive operation.

Using `useRef` will preserve state without rerendering.